# Alternative to using enums for specifying types in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, subclass

In my application I am developing an Entity-Component-System and I need a way of getting objects by their type from a Map. Currently I am doing this:

```
class Entity {
  components: Map<CT, Component>;

  constructor() {
    this.components = new Map();
  }

  get(componentType: CT): any {
    return this.components.get(componentType);
  }
}

const enum CT {
  Null,
  Health,
  Position,
  // etc..
}

class Component {
  type: CT;

  constructor(type: CT) {
    this.type = type;
  }
}

class HealthComponent extends Component {
  amount: number;
  
  constructor() {
    super(CT.Health);

    this.amount = 0;
  }
}
```

And then here is some example client code:

```
let healthComponent = new HealthComponent();
healthComponent.amount = 100;

let entity = new Entity();
entity.components.set(healthComponent.type, healthComponent);

// Later, elsewhere..
let health = entity.get(CT.Health);
console.log(health.amount);
```

This all works, but it's a bit cumbersome. Every new component I make requires me to make a new entry in the `CT` enum, and for me to make sure it matches in the new type's constructor. Ideally I'd like to be able to just do something like:

```
let healthComponent = new HealthComponent();
healthComponent.amount = 100;

let entity = new Entity();
entity.components.set(HealthComponent, healthComponent);

// Later, elsewhere..
let health = entity.get(HealthComponent);
console.log(health.amount);
```

But I'm not sure if that is possible. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I would just use string as a key and do something like:

```
class Entity {
  components: Map<string, Component>;

  constructor() {
    this.components = new Map();
  }

  get(componentType: string): any {
    return this.components.get(componentType);
  }
}
```

And then use the `name` property of the class like that:

```
let health = entity.get(Health.name);
console.log(health.amount);
```

You will have to set `target` in your `tconfig` to `es6` or `esnext` file to make it work though.
This won't work for interfaces so if you are planning to use them it is also not a good approach.

Comment: Hmm, yeah I heard this approach might have compatibility issues, and also it seems like the performance could be worse doing this since the keys are somewhat long strings instead of simple integers. Still, I might do this ... not sure..

Comment: Wait, how long are these strings that it affects performance?  That sounds very unlikely to me.

Comment: @RyanPeschel The strings contain exactly your class name. The difference is not that big with the int. On the other hand, if you have two classes with the same name this approach wont work either. On the third (?) hand what you say about compatibility - where are you going to run that code? If in the server, just pack it inside a docker and you have no issues. If in the browser than it's not a good idea.